# My sql query for item search is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

Im building a restaurant website and i have to search for food items according to what the user inputs in the search bar.
I have to sort the results by the most relevant one

UPDATED:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchValue']))
{
function test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data); //whitespacess
 $data = stripslashes($data); //removes backslashes n clean data from 
   database or form
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data); //converts predefined characters to html 
  entities, encoding user input so that they cannot manipulate html codes
  return $data;
  }



    $inpText=$_POST['searchValue'];

    $searchData=test_input($inpText);

    $starString= strtolower('{$searchData}');
    $searchData = $conn->quote($starString);
    $searchDataStartMatch = $conn->quote("%".$starString);
    $searchDataEndMatch = $conn->quote($starString."%");
    $searchDataBothMatch = $conn->quote("%".$starString."%");


    $sql="SELECT * FROM food WHERE Food_Name like {$searchDataBothMatch} OR 
         Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataBothMatch}
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN Food_Name={$searchData} or Food_Description = 
                    {$searchData} THEN 0
                        WHEN Food_Name like {$searchDataEndMatch} or 
                        Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataEndMatch} THEN 1
                        WHEN Food_Name like {$searchDataBothMatch} or 
                        Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataBothMatch} THEN 2
                        WHEN Food_Name like {$searchDataStartMatch} or 
               Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataStartMatch} THEN 3
                 ELSE 4
          END";

    $res=$conn->query($sql);



    if ($res->rowCount()>0)
    {
        while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-3 mx-0">
            //the code continues here
```

I have re formatted the latest sql statement and have executed the query but still it does not give me any desired output.. Now how shall i proceed?

Comment: You need LIKE in the ORDER BY's CASE.

Comment: @jarlh it partially works. Thanks

Comment: How about if i added Food_Description also to the search query that is i compare Food_Name and Food_Description  to what the user has input? How shall i add it?

Comment: Ask another question. Include sample table data and the expected result that time. [mcve]

Comment: BTW, you could simplify your current query: `POSITION(searchData IN LOWER(Food_Name))` will return the start position, can be used in both WHERE and ORDER BY.

Comment: @jarlh, i dont know how to properly format it :/

Comment: Incidentally, are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation?

Comment: @Strawberry if i don't convert it, it does not give me the proper output

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. Don't use `test_input()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use variables in the string. You are using PDO, therefore, use prepared statements instead.

Also if I understood correctly you need the "LOWER" function for the string you are searching right? in that case, use PHP "strtolower" function once and give that variable to SQL statement

```
$searchData= strtolower("{Some_text_to_search}");
$searchDataStartMatch = "%".$searchData;
$searchDataEndMatch = $searchData."%";
$searchDataBothMatch = "%".$searchData."%";
$sql="SELECT * FROM food WHERE Food_Name like ? OR Food_Description LIKE ?
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN Food_Name=? or Food_Description = ? THEN 0
                    WHEN Food_Name like ? or Food_Description LIKE ? THEN 1
                    WHEN Food_Name like ? or Food_Description LIKE ? THEN 2
                    WHEN Food_Name like ? or Food_Description LIKE ? THEN 3
             ELSE 4
      END";
$statement=$conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([
    $searchDataBothMatch,$searchDataBothMatch
    $searchData,$searchData,
    $searchDataEndMatch,$searchDataEndMatch,
    $searchDataBothMatch,$searchDataBothMatch,
    $searchDataStartMatch,$searchDataStartMatch
]);
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

**edited**

if you want to loop over results replace

> $results = $statement->fetchAll();

with:

```
$result = [];
while($row = $statement->fetch()){
    // your logic here
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

If you Cannot or dont want to use prepared statemants then do so:

```
$starString= strtolower("{Some_text_to_search}");
$searchData = $conn->quote($starString);
$searchDataStartMatch = $conn->quote("%".$starString);
$searchDataEndMatch = $conn->quote($starString."%");
$searchDataBothMatch = $conn->quote("%".$starString."%");
$sql="SELECT * FROM food WHERE Food_Name like {$searchDataBothMatch} OR Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataBothMatch}
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN Food_Name={$searchData} or Food_Description = {$searchData} THEN 0
                    WHEN Food_Name like {$searchDataEndMatch} or Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataEndMatch} THEN 1
                    WHEN Food_Name like {$searchDataBothMatch} or Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataBothMatch} THEN 2
                    WHEN Food_Name like {$searchDataStartMatch} or Food_Description LIKE {$searchDataStartMatch} THEN 3
             ELSE 4
      END";
$statement=$conn->query($sql);

$result = [];
while($row = $statement->fetch()){
    // your logic here
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: how shall i verify if the query has returned at least 1 number of row and how to loop over each result? I am used to working without prepared statements

Comment: @0x1234 I have modified answer to show how to loop over each result

Comment: @0x1234 can you please tell me what exactly is not working? does it show the error? Or data is not fetching?

Comment: @0x1234 try calling print_r($conn->errorInfo()); print_r($res->errorInfo()); to check if there is any error.

Comment: the error seems to be in the query as it is not getting any output

Comment: @0x1234 add print_r($statement->errorInfo()); die(); after query to check if there is any error. also make sure you have enabled error_reporting, at the beggening of file add: ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporing(E_ALL);

Comment: I added the LOWER to Food_Name and Food_Description.. it  worked butgiving me only 1 output. I wanted if the user typed for e.g ('chicken'), it shall give chicken related dishes

Comment: Btw, what does the THEN 0, THEN 1,... mean?

Comment: @0x1234 It should return everything Chichen related, can you provide some examples of strings which was not selected but should be in the result set?

In your SQL  "THEN 0" indicates cases when string you are searching for exactly matches Food_Name or Food_Description, the value is 0 to show the results first and so on. it's used to correctly sort your result, you should consider which case is more priority to set lowset number. for example 0 for full match, 1 for starting match, 2 for middle match, 3 for end match

Comment: Thank youu. Actually, it is quickly displaying the result and disappearing. I guess it is some issue with ajax call

Answer (score -1):

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM food WHERE LOWER(Food_Name) LIKE '%".$searchData."%'
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN LOWER(Food_Name)='".$searchData."' THEN 0
                        WHEN LOWER(Food_Name)='".$searchData."%' THEN 1
                        WHEN LOWER(Food_Name)='%".$searchData."%' THEN 2
                        WHEN LOWER(Food_Name)='%".$searchData."' THEN 3
                        ELSE 4
```

$searchData is variable that must be embedded in $sql with a period (.)

Comment: Not my downvote, but the concatenating is not needed here, as the `$sql` string is enclosed in double-quotes. I'd be more worried about inputting variables directly in a query without a placeholder....

Comment: See Variable Parsing in Double Quoted String Literals [The manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Use prepared statements.